# Mini cart not working with breeze cache plugin, working randomly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breeze

We tried pretty much everything, but without success. Mini cart is working randomly. One time it is working on homepage, but not other page, next time it is not working on categories page and so on. We tried it with and without varnish. Our functions file looks like this:

```php
<?php

add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'wc_refresh_mini_cart_count');

function wc_refresh_mini_cart_count($fragments){
    ob_start();
    if (sprintf('%d', WC()->cart->cart_contents_count) > 0) {
        ?>
        <div id="mini-cart-count">
            <?= sprintf('%d', WC()->cart->cart_contents_count) ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    else {
        ?>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery(function($){ 
                $('.navigation-cart').removeClass('colorized');
            })
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    $fragments['#mini-cart-count'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', function($fragments) {    
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="cart-content-wrapper">
        <?php woocommerce_mini_cart() ?>
    </div>

    <?php
    $fragments['div.cart-content-wrapper'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;
});
```

And I'll post our header code and full functions in comment in comment due to length of question.

I suspect that this is a problem in our theme, but I can't figure out what exactly the problem is.

Comment: No one's gonna read that wall of code - please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: This is our header code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rmtj-wi7x

Comment: And this is our full functions.php code http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/humy-0mq3